# Listener no funciona correctamente

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Tengo un `TableView` que contiene horas para seleccionar. Hay un botón "`Aceptar`" que se activa si se dan dos condiciones. Para ello, tengo un `listener` que se ejecuta cada vez que se selecciona un elemento y comprueba si se dan. Cuando selecciono elementos funciona correctamente, el problema es cuando deselecciono ya que no se ejecuta. Es decir, si mantengo "`ctrl`" y voy seleccionando con el raton elementos el `listener` se ejecuta. Pero si, manteniendo "`ctrl`", voy deseleccionando los `items`, el `listener` no se ejecuta ¿Alguna idea?
El código es el siguiente:

```
tablaHorario.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
        .addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
    ObservableList<ListaItem> selectedItem = tablaHorario.getSelectionModel()
             .getSelectedItems();
    boolean hCons = horasConsecutivas(selectedItem);
    if(hCons){
        horasConsLabel.setVisible(true);
        validHora.setValue(false);
    }
    else{
        horasConsLabel.setVisible(false);
        for(int i = 0; selectedItem != null && i < selectedItem.size(); i++){
            if(selectedItem.get(i).getEstado()){
                validHora.setValue(true);
            }
            else{
                validHora.setValue(false);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
                
    System.out.println("Hola");
});
<hr>   

 selectedItem = lista con los items seleccionados.
 horasConsecutivas() = método que devuelve true si las horas seleccionadas son consecutivas.
 validHora = boolean property que modifica el estado del boton de Aceptar.
 getEstado() = método que devuelve true si la hora puede ser seleccionada
```

El botón de "Aceptar" se activará sólo si las horas seleccionadas no son consecutivas y si todas las horas seleccionadas son válidas para ser seleccionadas (por eso el el bucle for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas es un [ListChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.html) con esto puedes monitorear cualquier cambio en las selecciones.

SelectionListener es más puntual.

Comment: Bien, como ya leíste mí mensaje procedo a borrarlo.